# New AD users not being added to Global Address List / unable to configure new user on outlook

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, outlook-2007

I just added a new user to AD and generated a mail box for her. When I go to configure outlook on her machine, I get the error "The name cannot be resolved. The name cannot be matched to a name in the address list"

I've regenerated the OAB and even recreated the AD object with no luck. I can not see the new user from the GAL on my machine, even when working online vs. cached.

However, I can log in to the new mailbox via OWA, see the recipient in that address list, and send and receive mail.

I've tried just about every fix I've stumbled upon with no success.

Using exchange 2010 on a single domain with less than 200 users. We are using outlook 2007 as the client.

Any guidance would be most appreciated! Thank you

Comment: How many Domain Controllers do you have? Are your users in a different AD site than the DCs? Are all of your DCs global catalogs? Do you have any replication problems?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a wonderful step-by-step guide called ["Troubleshooting Check Name errors"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297801) for this exact type of situation.

If you have already verified that the object has properly replicated after creation, this is definitely a place to start.

The most interesting part starts at step 3:

> Verify that the user account has been stamped by the Recipient Update
>   Service after you mailbox-enable the user account. To do so, start
>   Ldp.exe, use the user credentials to bind, and then verify that the
>   following attributes have been populated to the account:
>
> - `showInAddressBook()`
> - `textEncodedORAddress`
> - `msExchUserAccountControl`
> - `msExchALObjectVersion`
> - `msExchPoliciesIncluded`
>
> If these attributes are populated, the Recipient Update Service has
>   stamped this user account. If these attributes have not been
>   populated, troubleshoot the Recipient Update Service and the recipient
>   policies to determine why the attributes have not been stamped.

Another place to go if you have Outlook connectivity issues is Microsoft's onlince Remote Connectivity tool: https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

Comment: I checked in Ldp and did not see those attributes tagged to the user. I am a bit green when it comes to RUS and Exchange 2010. Last time I messed with it was on a 2003 console. Do you have any recommendations on articles that would help diagnose the issue on 2010?

Comment: And to my understanding, I thought Exchange 2010 dropped RUS for Address Policy. Is this correct?